# DependencyProperty -> AddOwner

Tags: wpf

I wonder whether I need to call AddOwner() when I do not intend to change the Metadata for a DependencyObject. I changed a small demo program to directly use an existing DependencyObject and it does not seem to change behavior.

Existing code:

```
FontSizeProperty = Control.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TextLabel));
```

My code:

```
FontSizeProperty = Control.FontSizeProperty;
```

Comment: It needs to be based on DependencyObject. What other dependency would that then be?

Answer (score 1):

You only need

```
  FontSizeProperty = Control.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TextLabel));
```

If you intend to add metadata specific to the new owner .

for instance a propertychange callback delegate or a default value.

Comment: That's what I figured. I was just unsure as no tutorial or article mentions this fact. They all give the impression I would need to use AddOwner because I use the Property in my class.

Comment: look in TextBlock.CS , they use a neat trick of exposing attached properties as Dependency properties of TextBlock . using AddOwner